# Firefox en_GB HTML5 date fields are in MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: firefox, html, language, html5, locale

On macOS Catalina, I've installed `en_GB` Firefox, my language preferences are 'Choose languages for menus messages etc' is "English (United Kingdom)", in "language for displayed pages" I've remove en_US, put `en-gb` as 1st priority and `en` as second and last language, and yet any HTML5 date field ([for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)) are not displayed in the "european" DD/MM/YYYY as they are in chromium based browsers I got (Brave for example)

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself, unfortunately I don't know what setting I've changed (it would've been in MacOS since FF prefs changed didn't have an effect). But if I find out I shall answer. It might have read in 'Language & Region' system preferences